# magento calculate average rating for categories based on products ratings

Tags: magento, categories, rating

I need to display rating on categories.

I was thinking to get that ratings from products in category and make an average.

It seems to be 'heavy' and it may be slowing down the website speed.

Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I recently solved this.I'll explain first after i'll give you the code :).

### 1. Storage

Indeed,the first problem is the optimization.How I solved that is that i stored the rating in the database with a cron job.its not online yet,but it will run every night or something.

### 2. Calculating

First of all,I took all the subcategories,(i dont need the root categories but if you do you'll figure out from the code how to get them) -> i got all the products of a category checked for rating for each product -> added the percents to array -> calculate mean value -> write/update (depends on if there is) a review(programatically) -> add/update rating to a review(programatically) -> repeat for all the categories.

### 3. The Code

```
include ('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$_categories = $_helper -> getStoreCategories();

$cateogory_ids = array();

if (count($_categories) > 0) :
    foreach ($_categories as $_category) :
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category') -> load($_category -> getId());
        $_subcategories = $_category -> getChildrenCategories();
        if (count($_subcategories) > 0) :
            foreach ($_subcategories as $_subcategory) :
                $cateogory_ids[] = $_subcategory; // get all the subcategories as objects
            endforeach;
        endif;
    endforeach;
endif;
$review_per_category = array();
$store_id = Mage::app() -> getStore() -> getId();


foreach ($cateogory_ids as $category) {

    $collection = $category -> getProductCollection();
    $collection -> addAttributeToSelect('*');
    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        $summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary') -> setStoreId($store_id) -> load($product -> getEntityId());
        $review_per_category[] = $summaryData['rating_summary']; // get the rating of all the products from this category
    }
    $review_per_category = array_filter($review_per_category);
    $count = count($review_per_category);    

    $sum = array_sum($review_per_category);
    $total = $sum / $count; 
    $review = Mage::getModel('review/review')->load($category -> getId(),'entity_pk_value');  // try to load the category review,if there is -> update else -> create
    $total_rating_option = round($total / 20); // rating percentage
    if(trim($review->getReviewId()) == ""){
    // create review and rating branch;
        echo $category -> getId().' review not found.Writing review<br/>';
        $_review = Mage::getModel('review/review')
            ->setEntityPkValue($category->getId())
            ->setStatusId(1)
            ->setTitle($category -> getName().' Category Review')
            ->setDetail($category -> getName().' Category Review')
            ->setEntityId(3)
            ->setStoreId($store_id)                
            ->setNickname('Auto')
            ->save();
        $rating_options = array(
            1 => array(1,2,3,4,5), 
            2 => array(6,7,8,9,10),
            3 => array(11,12,13,14,15),
            4 => array(16,17,18,19,20)    // we use custom rating options as 4.but the theory is the same. the 4th is kind of the sum of the first 3.    
        );


        foreach($rating_options as $rating_id => $option_ids){
            if($rating_id != 4)
                continue;
            try {
                if($_review -> getId() != ""){ 
                    $_rating = Mage::getModel('rating/rating')
                        ->setRatingId(4)
                        ->setReviewId($_review->getId())
                        ->setPercent($total) 
                        ->addOptionVote($option_ids[$total_rating_option-1],$category->getId());
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }else{
         // update rating branch;
         $rating_options = array(
            1 => array(1,2,3,4,5), 
            2 => array(6,7,8,9,10),
            3 => array(11,12,13,14,15),
            4 => array(16,17,18,19,20)        
        );
            $percent = array(
                        16 => 1,
                        17 => 2,
                        18 => 3,
                        19 => 4,
                        20 => 5,
                            );
        $rating = Mage::getModel('rating/rating_option_vote') -> load($category->getId(),'entity_pk_value');
        foreach($rating_options as $rating_id => $option_ids):
            if($rating_id != 4)
                continue;
            try {                
                $rating -> setOptionId($option_ids[$total_rating_option-1],$category -> getId())
                        -> setPercent($total)
                        -> setValue($percent[$option_ids[$total_rating_option-1]])
                        -> save()
                        ;
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }
        endforeach;
    }
    $review_per_category = array();
}
```

### 4. Summary

Of course i did not do all of this by myself.
If you have any questions feel free to ask me.
Good luck with that! :)

### 4.1. Database

The tables where you should check for the changes are 'rating_option_vote' and 'review_detail'